# Object equality comparison for input[radio] with ng-model and ng-value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let me start by saying that this question is very similar to issues with selection in a `<select>` tag using ng-options. For example, [Working with select using AngularJS's ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-ng-options-in-angular). The specific problem is comparing two different instances of an object which are not reference equal, but which logically represent the same data.

To demonstrate, let's say we have the following array of options and selected option variable in the model:

```
$scope.items = [
   {ID: 1, Label: 'Foo', Extra: 17},
   {ID: 2, Label: 'Bar', Extra: 18},
   {ID: 3, Label: 'Baz', Extra: 19}
];
$scope.selectedItem = {ID: 1, Label: 'Foo'};
```

Note that the above objects are just for demonstration. I specifically left off the 'Extra' property on `selectedItem` to show that sometimes my model objects differ in their specific properties. The important thing is that I want to compare on the ID property. I have an `equals()` function on my real objects that compares both prototype 'class' and ID.

And then in the view:

```
<label class="radio inline" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-value="item"> {{item.Label}}
</label>
```

Now, the problem here is that the radio button for 'Foo' will not start selected, because angular is using reference equality for the objects. If I changed the last line in my scope to the below, everything would work as expected.

```
$scope.selectedItem = items[0];
```

But, the problem I'm having is that in my application, I'm not simply declaring these two simple variables in scope. Rather, the options list and the data structure where the selected option are being bound are both part of larger sets of JSON data that are queried from the server using $http. In the general case, it's very difficult for me to go change the data-bound selected property to be the equivalent option from my data query.

So, my question:
In ng-options for the `<select>`, angular offers a `track by` expression that allows me to say something like "object.ID" and inform angular that it should compare the selected model value to the options via the ID property. Is there something similar that I can use for a bunch of radio inputs all bound to the same model property? Ideally, I would be able to tell angular to use my own custom equals() method that I've placed on these model objects, which checks both object type as well as ID. Failing that though, being able to specify ID comparison would also work.

Comment: We solved this with [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) method from underscore.js by selecting the value from options at start. I would also like to know if it can be done that way.

Comment: I'm not using undescore.js, but I don't mind rolling my own comparison function to do what I need. Where did you actually employ findWhere? In a custom directive?

Comment: Yes, we had radio button, dropdown directives just for this.

Comment: I would be curious to know how you structured the directives in your solution. That might actually be my answer.

Comment: Here is a [radio button directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/E3c6uwMnqIckTJmqAylO?p=preview). It's a little complex because it still works even if you load the options with an AJAX call. You may want to make it simpler.

Comment: I think your radio button directive is the answer I'm looking for. I am going to go ahead with implementing a directive along the same lines that suits my particular situation, but why don't you go ahead and write up your comment as an answer so I can give you credit on SO.

Comment: I just ran into this problem... If you take your example, even if you had `$scope.selectedItem = {ID: 1, Label: 'Foo', Extra: 17};` where all properties are included and equal, it still doesn't become selected. I thought this case would've been covered but it seems not :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I write a most simple directive. Using a kind of "track-by" to map two different objects. See the http://jsfiddle.net/xWWwT/146/.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-app ng-controller="ThingControl">    
    <ul >
        <li ng-repeat="color in colors">
            <input type="radio" name="color" ng-model="$parent.thing" ng-value="color" radio-track-by="name" />{{ color.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    Preview: {{ thing }}
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ThingControl', function($scope){
    $scope.colors = [
        { name: "White", hex: "#ffffff"},
        { name: "Black", hex: "#000000"},
        { name: "Red", hex: "#000000"},
        { name: "Green", hex: "#000000"}
    ];

    $scope.thing = { name: "White", hex: "#ffffff"};

});

app.directive('radioTrackBy', function(){
return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            ngModel: "=",
            ngValue: "=",
            radioTrackBy: "@"
        },
        link: function (ng) {   
            if (ng.ngValue[ng.radioTrackBy] === ng.ngModel[ng.radioTrackBy]) {                                
                ng.ngModel = ng.ngValue;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: With a few small modifications, I got this to work for `mdSelect` elements too.  https://gist.github.com/jonahbron/7a1f0c5bff949e3765b6

Comment: I have it working with complex model after adding `require: 'ngModel'` to the directive

Answer (score 2):

OK, so after further review, I decided to go with a more "mix-in" approach, just replacing the ng-model directive with my own custom directive, in essence. This is very similar to the approach I used for making a "checkbox list" directive based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14519881/561604.

```
.directive('radioOptions', function() {
    // Apply this directive as an attribute to multiple radio inputs. The value of the attribute
    // should be the scope variable/expression which contains the available options for the
    // radio list. Typically, this will be the collection variable in an ng-repeat directive
    // that templates the individual radio inputs which have radio-options applied. In addition,
    // instead of the normal ng-model, use a selected-option attribute set to the same expression.
    // For example, you might use radio-options like this:
    // <label ... ng-repeat="item in collection">
    //     <input type="radio" ... ng-value="item" radio-options="collection" selected-option="myModel.myProperty">
    // </label>
    //
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281404/object-equality-comparison-for-inputradio-with-ng-model-and-ng-value
    // for the SO question that inspired this directive.
    return {
        scope: {
            radioOptions: '=',
            selectedOption: '=',
            ngValue: '='
        },
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs ) {
            var modelChanged =  function() {
                if( jQuery.isArray(scope.radioOptions) ) {
                    jQuery.each( scope.radioOptions, function(idx, item) {
                        // This uses our models' custom 'equals' function for comparison, but another application could use
                        // ID propeties, etc.
                        if( typeof item.equals === 'function' && item.equals(scope.selectedOption) ) {
                            elem.prop( 'checked', item === scope.ngValue );
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            scope.$watch( 'radioOptions', modelChanged );
            scope.$watch( 'selectedOption', modelChanged );
            var viewChanged = function() {
                var checked = elem.prop( 'checked' );
                if( checked ) {
                    scope.selectedOption = scope.ngValue;
                }
            };
            elem.bind( 'change', function() {
                scope.$apply( viewChanged );
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the ID for the select like this?

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-value="item.ID"> {{item.Label}}
```

And then instead of using `selectedItem` you could write `items[selectedItem]`.

Oh, and while playing with your problem in jsfiddle I noticed to other things:

a.) You forgot to add a `name` attribute to the input.

b.) Don't ever use something without a dot in ng-model. If you actually try to output selectedItem with `{{selectedItem}}` outside the ng-repeat block, you will notice that the value does not update when you chose a radio button. This is due to `ng-repeat` creating a own child scope.

Comment: Yes, I see that would work in the limited example I posted. However, the problem I'm having is that in my actual application, I am indeed using a property of another object in ng-model. That property needs to be maintained with the actual object instance, not its ID.

Answer (score 1):

As OP requested, here's an example [radio button directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/E3c6uwMnqIckTJmqAylO?p=preview) that will work with complex objects. It uses [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) to find the the selected item from the options. It's a little more complicated than it should be because it also supports loading the options and selected value with AJAX calls.

Comment: you hardcoded the the value comparator, you could use angular.equals instead

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not yet able to add comments, so I have to reply here. Dana's answer worked ok for me. Although I'd like to point out in order to use his approach, one would have to implement the 'equals' function on the objects in the collection. See below example:

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   var eq = function(obj) {
       return this.id === obj.id;
     };
   col = [{id: 1, name: 'pizza', equals: eq}, {id:2, name:'unicorns', equals: eq}, {id:3, name:'robots', equals: eq}];

   $scope.collection = col;
   $scope.my = { favorite : {id:2, name:'unicorns'} };

 }]);
```

See the plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/aUbe8uPOmUdU7HNvP6l0?p=preview).

Comment: Yes, this is more or less how my code works. If all of your objects have an 'id' property though, it might be easier just to modify this line in the directive:

    `if( typeof item.equals === 'function' && item.equals(scope.selectedOption) ) {`

To simply check:

    `if( item.id === scope.selectedOption.id ) {`

But, you might have to do some null checks in there, not sure.

Comment: I actually prefer the equals function as it gives calling client more flexibility as to how to do the comparisons. The application of command pattern springs to mind...