# How do I do this ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of objects like this :

```
 $scope.list =  [ { id : 1, value : "one"}, 
                  { id : 2, value : "two"},
                  { id : 3, value : "three"} ];
```

I want it to output a list like this :

```
 <select>
     <option value="1">one</option>
     <option value="2">two</option>
     <option value="3">three</option>
  </select>
```

What is the ng-options syntax required to do this?

Comment: **Duplicate** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-ng-options-in-angular

Comment: One More possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller = "fessCntrl"> 
 <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="selectedItem as selectedItem.value for selectedItem in list" ></select>   
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $scope.list =  [ { id : 1, value : "one"}, 
              { id : 2, value : "two"},
              { id : 3, value : "three"} ];
 // select 1st by default
 $scope.selectedItem = $scope.list[0];
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/641/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You could try this;

```
<select name="yourname" ng-options="option.id as option.value for option in list"></select>
```