# Posting from AngularJS form to Web Api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post my Angular form to my Post method in my Api Controller :

```
    <div data-ng-app="app" ng-controller="FixtureAddController">
    <form name="form" class="col-xs-2" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: form.StageName.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label" for="StageName">Stage Team</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="fixture.StageName" ng-options="stage.StageName as stage.StageName for stage in stages" required>
                    <option style="display:none" value="">Select</option>
                </select>
                <span ng-show="form.StageName.$dirty && form.StageName.$error.required">Stage required</span>
            </div>
        </div>

....other fields....

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button ng-show="form.$valid" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary">{{action}}</button>
            <a href="/Admin/Fixtures/List" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Whether I set ng-model to fixture.StageName or fixture.StageId, it always passes the StageName to my Post method, but I need it to pass the StageId.  How do I get the Id to be passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
ng-options="stage.StageId as stage.StageName for stage in stages"
```

Comment: 'Identity gives me a syntax error : Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'identify' is an unexpected token at column 7 of the expression [stage identify by stage.StageId] starting at [identify by stage.StageId].

Comment: Seems to work, but without the 'stage identify' at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Try changing ng-options as well to use StageId.
See also: [Working with select using AngularJS's ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-ng-options-in-angular)