# How to bind select with existing model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `select` with existing `options`, I need to bind values from select to my model.

What I do:

```
<select ng-model="site.id">
    <option value="1">First<option>
    <option value="2">Second<option>
</select>
```

Where my model is: `user = ['name':'andry', 'site': {'id': 1, name: 'First'}]`

I want to bind this select with my model. How is it possible? Currently after choosing value from select site id will be updated, but site name - not.

I'm newbie in angular.

Comment: Why would not you use ng-options?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-ng-options-in-angular

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Comment: @ArtyomPranovich, actually, options rendered from server-side, so they  are predefined. Is there way, how to get options from select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, for working with select, use ng-options:

**View:**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Select something below</h1>
    <select id="s1" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"></select>
    <h3>The selected item:</h3>
    <pre>{{selectedItem}}</pre>
  </body>
```

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'bar' },
    { id: 3, name: 'blah' }
  ];
```

And see next [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/c98P0pKgPfVTi7rGrGxy?p=preview)

`$scope.selectedItem` contain full object from `$scope.items` array.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use option with ng-repeat is also fine:

### Assign model and value be object

```
<select ng-model="site">
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item}}" 
            ng-selected="site === item">{{item.name}}<option>
</select>
```

Comment: Accepted answer looks more angularish. and I have prerendered options from server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $watch function from angular

```
$scope.$watch("site.id", function(){
 var new_id = $scope.site.id;
 // so you now new id change site name
 $scope.site.name = "asdfasdfasdf"
});
```

Read [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, one more question: how to get value from choosen option?

Comment: you can do it by access $scope, like in answer

Comment: options are pre-rendered from server-side, not with angular, is it possible to get options from select?

Comment: @FUserThrowError, please, add check on not 'undefined' for site.id in watcher :)

Comment: @FUserThrowError, Not exactly, what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe i don't understand the problem as i must )) Can you say what is problem)) We can solve it)

Comment: As I wrote before, options are pre-rendered from server-side, not with angular, so I need to know site.id and site.name?