# Not working ng-options in SELECT

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to populate `States` in `Select` with `ng-options`. As i am new to angular, result doesn't come as expected.

Controller

```
$scope.statesList = function () {
        StatesList.query(function (states) {
            $scope.states = states;            
        });
    };
```

Html

```
<td data-ng-init="statesList()">
    <select ng-model="practiceAdd.state" name="state{{$index+1}}" ng-class="{'has-error': editForm.{{$index+1}}.$invalid}" 
        ng-options="state in states" required>
    </select>                                                                
</td>
```

Array

```
$$hashKey: "05S"
_id: "53107e099d985dc404000015"
city: "mumbai"
country: "india"
state: "AR"
street: "1"
zipcode: 42101
```

Comment: please post `$scope.states` array to help us to solve it.

Comment: Hi Check few url:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-ng-options-in-angular

Comment: @MaximShoustin I posted the Array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like This..

In HTML

```
<select name="countries" id="countries" ng-model="countryCode" ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in countries"></select>
```

In angular JS Code

```
  $scope.countries = [
    {
      name: 'Poland',
      code: 'PL'
    },
    {
      name: 'United Kingdom',
      code: 'UK'
    },
    {
      name: 'United States of America',
      code: 'USA'
    }
  ];
  $scope.countryCode = 'UK';
```

[Working Exaple](http://plnkr.co/edit/OprknQqK09sEVn67JHia?p=preview)

In your Example ;

```
<td>
    <select ng-model="state.Id" name="state{{$index+1}}" ng-options="state.Id as state.name for state in states" required>
    </select>                                                                
</td>
```

State id and state name should be defined by you.