# angularjs create dynamic dropdowns

Tags: angularjs

i want to create a form dynamically from a json string that is coming from a database. I am new to angularjs and I would like to know how to create a dropdown control dynamically within a repeater.  Below is an example of my code
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.fields = [
  {"reference_id":209,"form_id":1,"name":"firstname","label":"First               Name","type":"text"},
    {"reference_id":210,"form_id":1,"name":"lastname","label":"Last Name","type":"text"},
    {"reference_id":211,"form_id":1,"name":"email","label":"Email","type":"text"},
    {"reference_id":212,"form_id":1,"name":"picture","label":"Picture","type":"file"},
    {"reference_id":213,"form_id":1,"name":"address","label":"Address","type":"file"},
    {"reference_id":214,"form_id":1,"name":"select","label":"values","select       ng-model":"select"},   ];
```

Comment: Look at ng-options.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-ng-options-in-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in a comment, you'll want to use [`ngOptions`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

[**Plunk example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JLVlal7APqqYSX1gUqIL?p=preview)

You'll want to structure your html similar to this:

```
<select ng-model="currentField" ng-options="field.reference_id as field.label for field in fields"></select>
```

`currentField` will always result in a reference_id being selected. You can change it to name or any of the other properties of `$scope.fields`.

Comment: thank you for your insight. I am still a bit confused though since i want to build out a dynamic form which will include input textboxes/radio/checkboxes/dropdowns etc. If I were to change the model value of the last element to something like this:                     {"reference_id":214,"form_id":1,"name":"select","label":"values","type":"select", 
  "values": [ "Service 1", "Service 2", "Service 3", "Service 4"] }how would i decipher in my repeater to handle/distinguish this field? thank you so much for your help

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. haha.

Comment: @user3258918 it sounds like you want the form to build out dynamically based on a drop down? It's possible, but I'd need to have a better idea of what you are wanting the final product to be. 
Also, what things have you tried?

Comment: im pretty new to angular so i am unsure of how to build out a dynamic select control from a json string. text/radio and i am hoping select seems pretty straight forward i was hoping dropdowns would similar in angularjs

Comment: It still is not clear what you want. Is that what you're looking for:
A `select` box where an individual selects firstname, and then you create the input field for that?

Comment: No, I want to create a dynamic form from the json string. That is, three if the fields may be of type input text box but two May be dropdwn with values . A simple example of the end product would be first last name address (all text) gender state(drop downs)  see plker http://plnkr.co/tOe0fcpToBkupx0kSCKz

Comment: You continue to send the same plunker link. that is not helpful.
It may be more helpful if you take the time to write a new question and provide screenshots of what you are wanting to have happen. Regardless: here is an option to dynamically build forms: http://plnkr.co/edit/FFAeQlM2eUCv6pV8urYZ?p=preview. There are other ways as well, but we'll just wait for you to create a new question.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. But I think I've found a similar solution as to what I want to achieve here http://jsfiddle.net/StevenLJackson1/9Uf6C/7/ again thank you for your patience and help :)