# ng-options comprehension expression not working with my data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get my `<select>` to show every Route that is contained in the file `routes.json`. However, when I am using the ng-option, I can't seem to work out the correct expression to do so.

This is the data that gets loaded.  I want to put the destination of that route into the select box.

[image: loaded data]

**HTML**:

```
<label>Route: </label> <select ng-model = "selectBox2" ng-options="Route.destination for Route in data">  </select>
```

**Controller Code**:

```
kpsApp.controller('addMailItemController', function($scope,filefetch){
    $scope.price = 'priceless';

    filefetch.fetch().then(function(data){
        $scope.dataRoute = data;
    })
});
```

**EDIT**

**Route.json**:

```
{
  "Route": {
        "objectId": "ObjectRef",
        "origin": "Sydney",
        "destination": "Rome",
        "type": "Air",
        "maxWeight":"5000",
        "maxVolume":"29000",
        "wieghtCost":"1000",
        "volumeCost":"1000",
        "duration": "18hrs",
        "frequencyOfDeparture": "2 daily",
        "day":"Thursday",
        "company":"Transport Co.",
        "weightPrice":"7", 
        "volumePrice":"5",
        "priority": "International Air"
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

**fileFetch method**

```
kpsApp.factory('filefetch', function($q, $timeout, $http) {
    var getFile = {
        fetch: function(callback) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $timeout(function() {
                $http.get('../route.json').success(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                });
            }, 30);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
    return getFile;
});
```

Comment: Why dataRow? You Are confused it Works viceversa just use route

Comment: data is a json file. I updated the thread with the file.

Comment: I dont understand what you are referring to bto.rdz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you'd want, but check the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DqCUrFbVTtI4KuyDn5Ox?p=preview) I made to be sure:

```
<select ng-init="selectBox2 = selectBox2 || dataRoute[0].Route" ng-model="selectBox2" ng-options="datum.Route as datum.Route.destination for datum in dataRoute"></select>
```

To break the comprehension expression down into parts:

**datum.Route** (`select`) is what the model is populated with based on the user's selection
**AS datum.Route.destination** (`label`) sets which value the user sees
**FOR datum** (`value`) you could think of it as the iteration variable in a for/in loop... similar to the first part of an ngRoute expression
**IN dataRoute** (`array`) the source object, quite obviously

Following the use of this expression, your scope variable `selectBox2` would be populated with the complete "Route" entry of the selected record because we set it (the `select`) as the first part of the expression. As a result, you could use interpolation for properties like `{{selectBox2.destination}}` in your view.

You might find this article to be helpful: [Working with select using AngularJS's ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-select-using-angulars-ng-options)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! However it doesn't work when I am using a local JSON file, but it is working when i have the file statically inside my controller. I have posted the method which gets the data above, could it be how it is returning the data?

Comment: I can't say for sure what problem you're facing without having more detail, but I updated the Plunker so that it's using your factory (minus the $timeout which seemed unnecessary): http://plnkr.co/edit/DqCUrFbVTtI4KuyDn5Ox?p=preview

Comment: 'data' isn't reprenseted as an array, only as an object when i debug in webstorm. It only shows one of the routes even if i add in another.

Comment: It has to do with how your data is formatted. Can you update your question to include more than one entry so I can see how a complete file would be laid out?

Comment: Check out the .json file in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TNgdf9R6euFbenAg4EJR?p=preview) and let me know if it matches yours better (I bet it does). Then you can try out that expression on your side and I'll update my answer to reflect the change.

Comment: Not sure why, but after I tried again this morning it was working. Kind of curious why it is working now, and not last night without changing anything. However, thank you very much for your help, and I have marked your response as the answer.