# angularjs bootstrap, preset multiple selex box

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, select

I am having this issue and hope someone can help me.
Here's the code:

```
               <div class="country-form">
                <select multiple class="form-control">
                    <option ng-click="countryChanged(country)"
                            ng-model="selectedCountries" ng-repeat="country in options.countries">{{country}}
                    </option>


                </select>
            </div>
```

I have $scope.selectedCountries = []; in my controller 
I am not exactly sure how I can preset some countries.
Any help will be appreciated.

THank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with select using Angular's ng-options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-select-using-angulars-ng-options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-selected` in the options to preset some of the countries..

```
<option ng-selected="(selected.indexOf(country)!=-1)"
    ng-click="countryChanged(country)"
    ng-model="selectedCountries"
    ng-repeat="country in options.countries">{{country}}
</option>
```

Working demo: http://www.bootply.com/i3xutUdpeP

Comment: Thank you skelly, it works but what I don't understand is why you used $scope.selected as opposed to selectedCountries.Can't the ng-mode be used to preselect so that I can have them removed or added to the array automatically.

Comment: You can use "selectedCountries" if you want.. it's just a variable name.