# ng-options default value from external json file

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a select

```
data-ng-model="layout" ng-options="layout.url as layout.name for layout in layouts"
```

populated from an external json file:

```
{
"metaDescription": "My website description",
"metaKeywords": "keyword1, keyword2",
"siteTitle": "My Company",
"pageTitle": "Welcome ",
"layout": [
    { "name": "Cerulean",   "url": "cerulean" },
    { "name": "Cosmo",      "url": "cosmo" },
    { "name": "Cyborg",     "url": "cyborg" }
],
"test": "Lorem ipsum dolor"
}
```

And a controller

```
function httpController($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('content.json').success (function(data){

        $scope.layouts = data.layout;
        $scope.layout = $scope.layouts[2];
    });
};
```

The `$scope.layout = $scope.layouts[2];` should set as the default value but it does not work.

It seems to be working if the JSON array is in the controller but I need to use it **from an external JSON and in this case it does not work!**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `.url` to your `$scope.layout = $scope.layouts[2];`

In your `$http.get()` Do the following.

```
$http.get('URLToGET')
.success(function(data){
    $scope.layouts = data.layout;
    $scope.layout = $scope.layouts[2].url;  //<--- .url
});
```

Your HTML will look like this:

```
<select data-ng-model="layout" ng-options="layout.url as layout.name for layout in layouts">
     <option value="">Select Url</option>
</select>
```

**Here is a new updated working example**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {    
    
    $scope.data =  {
                        "metaDescription": "My website description",
                        "metaKeywords": "keyword1, keyword2",
                        "siteTitle": "My Company",
                        "pageTitle": "Welcome ",
                        "layout": [
                            { "name": "Cerulean",   "url": "cerulean" },
                            { "name": "Cosmo",      "url": "cosmo" },
                            { "name": "Cyborg",     "url": "cyborg" }
                        ],
                        "test": "Lorem ipsum dolor"
                      };
    
        $scope.layouts = $scope.data.layout;
        $scope.layout = $scope.layouts[2].url;
        
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  
    
     <select ng-model="layout" ng-options="layout.url as layout.name for layout in layouts">
          <option value="">Select Url</option>
     </select>
      <label ng-bind="layout"></label>

  </div>
  </div>
```

**For Some clarification**

> When you use `ng-options`, the values of option tags written out by
>   ng-options will always be the index of the array item the option tag
>   relates to. This is because Angular actually allows you to select
>   entire objects with select controls, and not just primitive types.

Refer to a [great answer by Ben Lesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-select-using-angulars-ng-options) for details on `ngOptions` as well as the [ngOptions official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Comment: I agree, but try to make this from an external JSON file! BTW my JSON as other values, this is the reason why i have the layout : [

Comment: I have updated the JSON as it is really (please see original question). It already as the opening/close {}. What I need to get it the url to inject in href="themes/{{layout}}/stylesheet.css" The Json is hosted here http://www.mailforce.fr/lists/content.json

Comment: @Artefact I see what you were referring to, check my update. Read the whole thing i pretty much re-wrote it :) it works now

Comment: I get $scope.layouts.layout is undefined

Comment: Thats because on my example i was retrieving a JSON object from your whole JSON. Check my updated answer which shows you the `$http.get`. Test it out with `JSON.parse(data.data)` if that doesnt do it then change the `data.data` to just `data` and let me know so i can update answer please.

Comment: I get SyntaxError: JSON.parse: $scope.layouts = JSON.parse(data).layout;

Comment: Ok i went ahead and tested this using a REST Mockup service `https://www.mockable.io`, awesome site. Using their trial i was able to replicate your `environment` and the incoming JSON you provided. So, with that said Look at my updated answer. Your `ng-options` was indeed correct from the beginning. Just change your `.success()` as I have it in the answer. All you were missing was - `.url` ;)

Comment: Thanks you Dayan, but on my hand $scope.layouts = data.layout; $scope.layout = $scope.layouts[2].url; does not put url2 as defautlt in the selest :(

Comment: Ok, do you want to display The `name` values in the dropdown and when one is selected then the model will equal the `url`? Or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the name value in the dropdown with a default on select and when one is selected get the corresponding URL which is in fact a folder name to add to href="themes/{{layout}}/stylesheet.css"

Comment: Then what i provided is correct. If that is the JSON you are refering to then I tested it externally via a 3rd party REST mockup service and locally. Works just fine, seems likr your doing something extra thats conflicting...

Comment: That was not working. I have a split $http.get > success in 2 parts.
1 with $scope.layouts = data.layout and one with $scope.layout = $scope.layouts[2].url; and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your ng-options like this:

```
ng-options="layout as layout.name for layout in layouts"
```

Your ng-options expression is in the following format:

**select** as **label** for **value** in array

Per angular documentation the definition of **select** is:

> The result of this expression will be bound to the model of the parent
>    element. If not specified, select expression will default to
>   value.

You are binding the url property to the model not the whole object.  That is the problem.

Comment: Add $scope.layout = {} at the top of your controller.

Comment: Sorry but it does not work. I mean, my code works as I get the right folder to populate <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/{{layout}}/stylesheet.css"> - but I am not able to get a default value to the select

Comment: I think you need to update the following line $scope.layouts = data.layout; to just $scope.layouts = data;

Comment: without success :( It works fine from an array in the Controller but not from an external .json file