# How to select option in Angular using ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-options` fo select list with next format data:

```
data.dateList.day =  [{"id":1,"value":1},{"id":2,"value":2},{"id":3,"value":3},...]
```

How I can select option using `ng-model` when value is equal 2, for example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-select-using-angulars-ng-options

Comment: There are many more... Also see [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using ng-selected as well.

Here is a plunker for you.

```
 <select>
      <option ng-repeat="day in days" ng-selected="{{day.id == 2}}" value="{{day.id}}">
        {{day.value}}
      </option>
  </select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DeT1RBr4hDQxX05Qd4ao?p=preview

Comment: But if I want select any value?

Comment: That will be done by ng-selected attribute.

Comment: I use `ng-options` inside `select`

Comment: Ok. I prefer to use ng-repeat in options as it adds clarity that which element is being repeated.

Comment: Can I do it with ng-options? or not

Comment: Yes why not. It is easier and simpler. See the code above or refer to plunker. In case anything not clear let me know.