# ng-options: How to access to position (index) in an object which has no index in key or value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, indexing, angularjs-ng-options

I have a JSON obj. as below:

```
[
   {"Title":"x", "Type":"y", "Desc":"First Description"},
   {"Title":"r", "Type":"q", "Desc":"Second Description"}
]
```

I want to have a drop-down including Titles in this obj (using `ng-options`). Then, I want to use the the Index of selected Title in the object. (Imagine the object will be used as array (called myArray), as what *user194715* answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-select-using-angulars-ng-options))
for example:

```
var type = myArray[selectedIndex].Type;
var description= myArray[selectedIndex].Desc;
```

How can I access to the index in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```js
var app = angular.module("app",  []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.myArray =
        [
          {"Title":"x", "Type":"y", "Desc":"First Description"},
          {"Title":"r", "Type":"q", "Desc":"Second Description"}
        ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="select" ng-options="key as value.Title for (key,value) in myArray">
   </select>
 <span>{{myArray[select].Type}}</span>
 <span>{{myArray[select].Desc}}</span>
</div>
```