# Angularjs ngrepeat and ngoptions, what is "as" "for" keyword?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
 $scope.items = [{
   id: 1,
   label: 'aLabel',
   subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
 }, {
   id: 2,
   label: 'bLabel',
   subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
 }];
```

based on above list, below is what I normally use:

```
<select ng-options="item in items" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Very straightforward, as in, I can access the value by using `item.xxx`

But what is the syntax below:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

I am totally blur, the `as` and `for` keyword is for what purpose? I could not really find the doc that explain this, please help.

PS:
Original syntax is `<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>` but I removed `track by`, because I understand that by reading from the doc.

Comment: Ref these links may it will help you    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-the-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-select-using-angulars-ng-options/13049740#13049740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the options list which `<select>` should refer to populate options.

```
 $scope.items = [{
   id: 1,
   label: 'aLabel',
   subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
 }, {
   id: 2,
   label: 'bLabel',
   subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
 }];
```

When you write `ng-options="item as item.label for item in items"`, you are iterating over `items`, where each item is assigned to `item` by using `item in items`.

So for 1st iteration, `item`'s value will be:

```
{
   id: 1,
   label: 'aLabel',
   subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
 }
```

Note that `item` is an *object* in this case.

`<option>` doesn't care about how you're fetching data for it, it only cares about what it needs to show and assign what value when it's selected. So, we tell `ng-options` using `for` that take `item` as input and generate corresponding `<option>` elements.

Now in select option, suppose you want your input to be `id`. But hey, who knows what is the meaning of your `id`, to be *human* readable you would want to display some meaning message to identify it, which is `label` in this case.

So, instead of using the entire object, you will use only it's `id` while using `label` to identify it(text displayed in dropdown).
Now your code changes to:

`ng-options="item.id as item.label for item in items"`

So the final generated HTML becomes something like this:

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">aLabel</option>
  <option value="2">bLabel</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ok, so in short, before `as` it is for the `option` value, and after `as` it is for the label content? But I copied the code from angularjs website(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), they are using `item` before `as` instead of `item.id`, although using `item.id` make more sense based on your explanation. why they are using `item`? what it mean then? what can be the option value if we use `item`?

Comment: @GMsoF Instead of picking just the `id` from the object, they are selecting the entire object. Implies, if you use `item` it'll select the entire object. I've created a plunk(https://plnkr.co/edit/pnJj4OND10enP2fXwLxq?p=preview) to help you understand this better.

Comment: I see! Previously I couldn't understand why it select entire object, because `option` value should be string value, plugging in object doesn't make sense. Now I know if the purpose is to use it together with the `select's ng-model`, then it make sense, although most of time, we want to submit the value to server, `select as object` will be unlikely to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official documentation in the ngOptions directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

`<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items" ng-model="selected"></select>` is almost similar in functionality  to 
`<select ng-options="item in items" ng-model="selected"></select>`

But here the first one is giving more clarity to the framework

in **`item as item.label for item in items`**,

**'as':** `item as item.label` is telling that in the options of select tag show `item.label`, **but** `item.label` representing whole **object item**. Which means that even though the option is showing only `item.label` in DOM, the other properties (id, subtype etc) are also accessible using the `ng-model` (or selected option)

**'for':** Here `for item in items` comes because when mentioning `item as item.label` the DOM has no idea what is this **`item`**. So this is clearly saying that the `item` in the statement of `item.label` is an `object` in the **object array `$scope.items` (or simply itmes in term of DOM)**