# AngularJS (1.5.8) - How do I populate a select option list directly from within controller that gets a json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have an AngularJS app that I want to populate a select drop down list from a JSON result.

The controller code gets the json but how do I populate the $scope.states.

My drop down remains empty on the fetch and the res of the page does not render.

$scope.accountAddresses is a JSON container with various data.  My concern is only for the shippingState key.

**HTML Code**

```
<select name="shippingState" id="shippingState"  ng-model="accountAddresses.shippingState"  class="state form-control" size="1">
```

**Controller JSON Fetch Code**

```
 $http.get( serviceBase + 'Assets/us-states.json').success(function(d){
            $scope.states = d;
      });
```

I tried `ng-repeat="state in $scope.states"` but I do not get any data (state abbreviations) in the drop down.

**JSON Sample Data**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Alabama",
        "abbreviation": "AL"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alaska",
        "abbreviation": "AK"
    }]
```

How do I get the population to work like the following html code of options?

```
 <option value="AK">AK</option>
<option value="AL">AL</option>
```

EDIT

With the following code

```
 <select name="shippingState" id="shippingState"  ng-model="accountAddresses.shippingState"  ng-options ="s.abbreviation as s.name for s in states" class="state form-control" size="1">
```

**I get the following, but I need to remove "string:" and label**

```
<option value="string:AL" label="Alabama">Alabama</option>
<option value="string:AK" label="Alaska">Alaska</option>
```

Comment: Post your json data

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I edited my post.

Comment: Try "ng-repeat="state in states""

Comment: I have tried with the modification of ng-repeat with no luck.  If it is worth mentioning I am using a plugin that styles the drop down. It has the effect of hiding the selection and creates a styled drop down with the dropdown data.

Comment: using `ng-options` not `ng-repeat` is the best practice. Also note that `$scope` doesn't exist in view...only the properties of `$scope` defined in controller do

Comment: Based on the responses I get a drop down with options with label as the state and the inner html as the full state name.  Seems I don't need options but instead value should be the abbrevation and InnerHTML equal to the full name.

Comment: @Vahe - you can modify my answer by changing the "as" from state.name to state.abbreviation and then modifying the "track by" to state.name

Comment: Thanks @Ryan27,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-select-using-angulars-ng-options     is a good example of what I need and seems to adddress the answers as well as well as your comment too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) for this.

Depending on what you want to show:

`<select ng-options="state as state.name for state in states track by state.abbreviation" ng-model="accountAddresses.shippingState"></select>`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) ,

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options ="s.name  for s in states"></select>
```

**Controller:**

```
  function($scope, $http) {
             $http.get('test.json').then(function (response){
                $scope.states = response.data;
                console.log(response);
        });
```

[`DEMO APP`](https://plnkr.co/edit/KeFIDwJVzhPD6DyYQnPQ?p=preview)