# Angular 1.5.8 - How do I perform an action when angular finishes binding data to an element?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an angular app in which I want to wait until data is bound to a selection drop down until before I apply a jquery method to the selection drop down.

In my previous related question I was able to populate the drop down successfully using the following code.

```
 <select name="shippingState" id="shippingState" ng-model="accountAddresses.shippingState"  ng-options ="state.abbreviation for state in states track by state.abbreviation" class="state form-control" size="1">
                       </select>
```

[AngularJS (1.5.8) - How do I populate a select option list directly from within controller that gets a json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476181/angularjs-1-5-8-how-do-i-populate-a-select-option-list-directly-from-within)

Now I want to apply the jquery method (a custom selectbox dropdown styling library).

When data loads, I am able to apply the method manually in the browser console.
The problem is I can only do the action in the browser console manually.

When the drop down data is fetching I can not run the same method in angular.

**Question:**
How do I can trigger an action when data binding finishes in Angular?

EDIT - I created a directive and modified my html to trigger the directive.

Still I do not get a custom styled element.

**Directive Chained to the Root Controller**

```
  directive('onDataBind', function (id) {
                        alert(id);
                          function link(elem, id) {
                            elem.ready(function(id){
                              $scope.CreateDropDown(id);
                              });
                            }
                          })
```

HTML Modified

```
           <select name="billingState" id="billingState" ng-model="accountAddresses.billingState"  ng-options ="state.abbreviation for state in states track by state.abbreviation" on-data-bind="CreateDropDown('billingState')" class="state form-control" size="1">
           </select>
```

Create Drop Down at the Scope Level

```
   $scope.CreateDropDown = function(id){
      $("#"+id).selectbox();
      //selectbox is the following library - https://github.com/olivM/jQuery-Selectbox
    }
```

Comment: Use a directive and `$timeout()`.

Comment: @Lex, you beat me to it.  Thanks for the help.  Please see edits.

Comment: I have no action working on this directive yet.  Do I need scope to be injected into the function link?

Comment: What is `CreateDropDown()`? That's a method on your scope? I thought you wanted to call some jQuery function? Also, that's not how you create a directive.

Comment: directive constructor is all wrong , a directive should return an object with properties like `link` .. `template` etc

Comment: My CreateDropDown is a function that calls a jquery libarary to style my drop down.  Let me post code on this method.

Comment: @charlietfl, I had it that way before, I just followed another section of the code I have, I am just getting familiar.

Comment: Don't put DOM manipulation code in your controller - that should all go in the directive.

Comment: I got a solution but is there any way without timeout?

Answer (score 0):

The following directive code helped resolve the issue.  I used a directive and timeout as suggested.

```
directive('onDataBind', function () {
                  function link(scope, elem) {
                    var id = elem.attr("id");
                    elem.ready(function(){
                     setTimeout(function () {
                       $("#"+id).selectbox();
                     }, 1000);
                      //$('#'+id + ' .sbHolder > .sbOptions').wrap("<div class='optionsDiv'></div>");
                      //$("#"+id + " .sbHolder > a.sbToggle, "+id+" + .sbHolder a.sbSelector").wrapAll("<div class='selectDiv'></div>");
                    })(id);
                    }
                    return {
                      link: link,
                      restrict: 'A',
                    };
                  })
```

Comment: Aside from timeout, is there a way to get "id" to be seen within elem.ready rather than the way I do right below the two commetned lines?