# working with select options and an object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to display category value in a dropdown using select options from this object:

```
[{
    "_id": "57b4508923a10cd83c79a301",
    "created_by": "1",
    "category": "Criminal law",
    "__v": 0,
    "delete_status": "0",
    "active_status": "1",
    "modified_date": "1471434889599",
    "created_date": "1471434889599"
}, {
    "_id": "57b466b34f94fc982a0d926d",
    "created_by": "1",
    "category": "Business Law",
    "__v": 0,
    "delete_status": "0",
    "active_status": "1",
    "modified_date": "1471440563159",
    "created_date": "1471440563158"
}, {
    "_id": "57c6be3ae74cdc1d6a9b2224",
    "created_by": "1",
    "category": "Corporate Law",
    "__v": 0,
    "delete_status": "0",
    "active_status": "1",
    "modified_date": "1472642618768",
    "created_date": "1472642618768"
}]
```

I used below code but got undefined:

```
<select ng-model="category" ng-options="users.id as users.category for item in items"></select>
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: <select ng-model="category" ng-options="users.id as users.category for item in items"></select>

Comment: What is "category", "users" and "items" ? Which of them are you displaying as JSON above?

Comment: i want to render like this  <select>
  <option value="57b4508923a10cd83c79a301">Criminal law</option>
  <option value="57b466b34f94fc982a0d926d">Business Law</option>
  <option value="57c6be3ae74cdc1d6a9b2224">Corporate Law</option>
</select>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with select using Angular's ng-options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-select-using-angulars-ng-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []).controller('countryCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.records = [{
      "_id": "57b4508923a10cd83c79a301",
      "created_by": "1",
      "category": "Criminal law",
      "__v": 0,
      "delete_status": "0",
      "active_status": "1",
      "modified_date": "1471434889599",
      "created_date": "1471434889599"
    }, {
      "_id": "57b466b34f94fc982a0d926d",
      "created_by": "1",
      "category": "Business Law",
      "__v": 0,
      "delete_status": "0",
      "active_status": "1",
      "modified_date": "1471440563159",
      "created_date": "1471440563158"
    }, {
      "_id": "57c6be3ae74cdc1d6a9b2224",
      "created_by": "1",
      "category": "Corporate Law",
      "__v": 0,
      "delete_status": "0",
      "active_status": "1",
      "modified_date": "1472642618768",
      "created_date": "1472642618768"
    }];
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="countryCtrl">
  <select ng-init="text._id = records[0]._id" ng-model="text" ng-options="record.category for record in records track by record._id">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: sure.. but {{category}} is not displaying any thing i need id in it.. its displaying nothing after selecting

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="category" ng-options="item.id as item.category for item in items"></select>
```

just update this in your template (y) :)