# Using ng-options with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, restful-url

I'm still trying to find my way with AngularJS. I have a JavaScript code that uses URL to return JSON data as an array. I need help with populating the same data in select using ng-options.
[data to populate on the select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1uBE.jpg)

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-select-using-angulars-ng-options might prove useful

Comment: Thanks man, the link helped I now see the light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't how you ask for help, but nevermind. Given a JSON object like this

```
var JsonArray = [{
    id: 1, 
    name: 'Jane',
    address: 'Jane\'s house'
}, {
    id: 2, 
    name: 'Jill',
    address: 'Jill\'s house'
}, {
    id: 3, 
    name: 'John',
    address: 'John\'s house'
}, {
    id: 4, 
    name: 'Jack',
    address: 'Jack\'s house'
}];
```

When you want to use ng-select with ng-options, you need to specify 3 required fields :

- your table
- the name that every object will take (like a for ... each loop)
- The property you want to see in your options

You also can specify a `track by` property to give your options a given value.

```
<select ng-model="mySelect" ng-options="object.name for object in JsonArray track by object.id"></select>
```

Now, use the last piece of code, and inspect it in a brwoser. You will understand everything.

For reference :

```
<select ng-model="mySelect" ng-options="[object].[chosenProperty] for [object] in [yourArray] track by [object].[property]"></select>
```

Comment: thanks. I copied the results and created a JSON file like you've done. It's working fine, what if I didn't have a  file or don't have to create that file? How can I do it without creating a file but to reference the output as displayed on the console.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. What do you exactly want to do ? Because I didn't create any file ...

Comment: I wanted to reuse the output of the URL call from the javaScript which display that JSON  data you've created at the top. I got it to work, it was just a matter of assigning ng-model withiin the <select> value to the response.data so that it can populate the drop-down.