# Get JSON data in drop down list using AngularJS.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

This is my HTML code

```
<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <select>
<option ng-repeat="person in persons">{{ person.data }}</option>
</select>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my JavaScript code

```
var app = angular.module("mainApp", []);
app.controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("JSON URL")
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.persons = response.data;
        });
});
```

My JSON URL is in this format `[{"status": "success", "data": ["bank1","bank2","bank3"]}]`, I want only "data" list in drop down, there is too many banks in JSON data, How to use select and option?

Comment: have you tried using `ng-options' like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-select-using-angulars-ng-options)

Comment: Consider using the `ng-options` directive. For more information, see [AngularJS ng-options Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

**Controller:**

```
app.controller("dobController", ["$scope", "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("test.json").then(function(response) {
      $scope.data = response.data[0].data;
      console.log($scope.data);
    })
  }

]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="dobController">
  <select class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelected" ng-options="selection as selection for selection in data"></select>
</body>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/gst54r2Ek3vholkpd6A1?p=preview)**

Comment: @shilpa you are welcom

Comment: If i select particular bank in the list, How to link the dependble drop down, with one more API which i have for next drop down? can u please help..

Comment: yes sure! do you want to call another api and get data?

Comment: yes with dynamic drop down, I have one more API of states list based on selecting particular bank, should i use ui-routing?

Comment: no need touse routing for that, do you have to pass selected bank as a parameter for the new api?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133406/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-shilpa).