# AngularJS ng-options not rendering values

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

How can I render the value of the following options list?

```
$scope.limits = [ {value:  '5', text: 'Afficher 5 par page'},
                  {value: '10', text: 'Afficher 10 par page'},
                  {value: '15', text: 'Afficher 15 par page'},
                  {value: '20', text: 'Afficher 20 par page'}
                ];

<select id="limitType" name="limit" ng-model="limit" ng-options="limit.value as limit.text for limit in limits"></select> enregistrement par page
```

Expected result (expecting in value="limit.value":

```
<select ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in limits" ng-model="limit" id="limitType" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option value="5" selected="selected">Afficher 5 par page</option>
    <option value="10">Afficher 10 par page</option>
    <option value="15">Afficher 15 par page</option>
    <option value="20">Afficher 20 par page</option>
</select>
```

Result:

```
<select ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in limits" ng-model="limit" id="limitType" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Afficher 5 par page</option>
    <option value="1">Afficher 10 par page</option>
    <option value="2">Afficher 15 par page</option>
    <option value="3">Afficher 20 par page</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `ng-options` directive does not set the `value` attribute on the `<options>` elements. It always uses a sequence.

Using `limit.value as limit.text for limit in limits` means:

- Set the `<option>`'s label as `limit.text`
- Save the `limit.value` value into the select's `ng-model`

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/k58Hw/

Comment: This behaviour allows one to use any type of object in select options, not only strings and numbers.

Comment: @bmleite That helped a lot! But what if i want to store the value in database via submitting form?

Answer (score 3):

To make it work, you (we) have to change the way we submit the data to the server.

The browser is "stupid", and it does not take care about AngularJS, jQuery or any other JavaScript framework doing magic in the code behind. If the option contains index value instead of real value, the browser will send the index value to the server.

If you want to make it work, you either have to use ng-repeat in conjunction with option tag to render correct values, or to submit data by calling the `.post` method from the AngularJS controller.

This is why I love & hate AngularJS.

Comment: I think the big issue that you may be struggling with here is trying to maintain a javascript MVC in an application that you do not accept as a SPA.  If you were to submit your `form` as a angular model with the `$http.post` or `$http.get` you wouldn't have the issues

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question but I had an issue with this too. My simple solution to this was to create a hidden input and bind it using ngModel with the select. Then when you do normal form submit, submit the hidden input. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

for an alternate approach, we can use ng-repeat

```
<select  ng-model="limit" id="limitType" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" >
 <option ng-repeat="option in limits " value="{{option.value}}" >
  {{option.text}}
 </option>
</select>
```