# angular ng-option Option and Label

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a Select field:

```
<select
    id="aircraft_id"
    data-id="{{( $obj->exists ) ? $obj->aircraft_id : NULL}}"
    data-placeholder="Wähle ein Flugzeug"
    no-results-text="'Konnte kein Flugzeug finden'"
    class="form-control"
    chosen="directiveOptions"
    name="aircraft_id"
    ng-model="aircraft"
    ng-change="checkSeats(aircraft.id)"
    ng-disabled="newAircraftIdentifier.length > 0 || newAircraftModel.length > 0"
    ng-options="aircraft.ident for aircraft in aircrafts">
</select>
```

and "aircrafts" json object contains:

```
[Object { ident="--", id="", seats=""}, 
 Object { id=1, ident="D-3417", seats=2}, 
 Object { id=2, ident="D-1021", seats=2}, 
 Object { id=3, ident="D-4582", seats=1}, 
 Object { id=5, ident="D-FTSD", seats=null}, 
 Object { id=10, ident="D-5970", seats=1}
]
```

Everything works except that my option in the select is the index of my json Object, and not the id...

so the result is the following:

```
<option value="0" selected="selected">--</option>
<option value="1">D-3417</option>
<option value="2">D-1021</option>
<option value="3">D-4582</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">D-FTSD</option>
<option value="5">D-5970</option>
```

But I want that the option value is my ID in the array like ID 10 in the last item, and not 5... 
Hope you understand what I mean.

I think the wrong line is this:

```
ng-options="aircraft.ident for aircraft in aircrafts"
```

But I dont understand how I fix this.

Thanks in advance,

Leif

Comment: `aircraft.ident for aircraft in aircrafts track by aircraft.id` should work

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-options not rendering values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425686/angularjs-ng-options-not-rendering-values)

Comment: thanks... now it is work... track by aircraft.id is the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
aircraft.id as aircraft.ident for aircraft in aircrafts
```

Comment: I try this before, but it isn't work... I found the solution: aircraft.ident for aircraft in aircrafts track by aircraft.id

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be concerned with `value` on `option` element as it's irrelevant with Angularjs model. DOM created with ng-options will have always values from 0..n, check your `$scope.aircraft` model for actually selected value

you can also use it as `aircraft.id as aircraft.ident for aircraft in aircrafts` then the model `$scope.aircraft` will be updated with only id