# AngularJS : how to create select option and set default select option?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I use AngularJS to create a html form. So in my form i have 2 text input and select option. The code is below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
            .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
                $scope.myForm = {};
                $scope.myForm.firstName = "Jakob";
                $scope.myForm.lastName = "Nielsen";
                $scope.myForm.town  = {name:"Not filled", value:"0"};
                $scope.towns  = [
                                            {name:"Not filled", value:"0"},
                                            {name:"New York", value:"1"},
                                            {name:"San Francisco", value:"2"},
                                            {name:"Boston", value:"3"},
                                            {name:"Miami", value:"4"}
                                        ];
            } );
</script>
<body ng-app="myapp">

<div ng-controller="MyController" >
    <form>
         First name : <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="myForm.firstName"> <br/>
         Last name : <input type="text" name="lastName"  ng-model="myForm.lastName">  <br/>
         Town : 
         <select ng-model="myForm.town" ng-options="town.value as town.name for item in towns"></select>



    </form>

    {{myForm.firstName}} | {{myForm.lastName}} | {{myForm.town.name}} | {{myForm.town.value}}

    <div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am facing two problem :
1. I cannot see option label. I don't understand. I use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425686/angularjs-ng-options-not-rendering-values) to write my select option. What's wrong please ?
2.In my controller i set the model of select option to have a option selected by default. I am wondering if it's the right way to do it ?

```
$scope.myForm.town  = {name:"Not filled", value:"0"};
```

Thank you for helping. Here is my  [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/OtNe5zWFPJ3gBmsnhcA6).

Comment: It's so much easier/faster to answer when you supply a plunker - good job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think it's alright to set the default in the model, I don't see a problem with it.

As to your label problem, you have used the wrong iterator `item in towns`, should have been `town in towns`

```
<select ng-model="myForm.town" ng-options="town.value as town.name for town in towns"></select>
```

Comment: Actually there is a problem in the way he did it. It didn't work because he didn't reference the model...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your plunker here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/pJyOGUtBRiaoeFYeEDFD?p=preview

The problems were:

1. Wrong syntax in ng-options. Should have been: `item.name for item in towns` or `town.name for town in towns`
2. You have to set the selected value to one of the objects in the source - not a new object:  `$scope.myForm.town = $scope.towns[0];`

There is another way you can solve the problem in 2. If you do not want to reference the correct object `$scope.towns[0]` then you can change the way angular tracks the model by specifying a [track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). You will need to change the ng-options to `town.name for town in towns track by town.value` but then you set the selected index like this: `$scope.myForm.town = {value : "1"};`