# AngularJS: Select Element - Have a different model and a value for options

Tags: angularjs

I have an javascript object as follows in my controller:

```
$scope.options = [
    {
        "actualValue": "age",
        "displayValue": "Age"
    },
    {
        "actualValue": "maiden",
        "displayValue": "Maiden Name"
    }
];
```

Now, I am displaying a select element in which the options of the element will be the values in the "displayValue" property written above:

```
<select ng-options="entry.displayValue for entry in options" ng-model="biodata">
    <options>-- Select a BioData Option --</option>
</select>
```

Now, my problem is that the `ng-model` for the select element above when the user select a value from the dropdown is the "displayValue" property. I wish that the `ng-model` be the "actualValue" property.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select ng-options="entry.actualValue as entry.displayValue for entry in options"></select>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rzV65/

Already answered here: [How do I set the value property in AngularJS' ng-options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options)