# Not able to set value to select tag using Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My task is very simple. I'm able to set values to text boxes that come from restful api.. I'm able to get and display on the raw HTML page using {{currentCommodity.commodityName}}  But, not able to set values to the select tag even though I'm able to get value.

My code is

```
$scope.editCommodity = function(commodityIndex) {           
        console.log("commodities object",$scope.commoditiesAdded[commodityIndex].commodityName);            
        $scope.currentCommodity.commodityName = $scope.commoditiesAdded[commodityIndex].commodityName;

}
```

It returns a commodity name with paddy..

### My HTML code

```
---{{currentCommodity.commodityName}}-
<select class="form-control selection_size" ng-change="selectunits(currentCommodity.commodityName.commodityID)" ng-model="currentCommodity.commodityName" ng-disabled="{{editBusinessFlag}}" ng-options="commodityitem.commodityName for commodityitem in commodityList">
    </select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood the requirement but would this be of any help? [**getting the ng-object selected with ng-change**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386570/getting-the-ng-object-selected-with-ng-change)

Comment: Can you please share it in jsfiddle?

Comment: @Archana, its very simple. I just want to assign the value to the select tag. I wish that I could create a fiddle, but I can't now.

Comment: Ok Mahesh i will try to give a solution for your problem

Comment: I think the answer in that question can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815036/setting-default-value-in-select-drop-down-using-angularjs?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
    You selected : {{currentCommodity.commodityName}}
    <select class="form-control selection_size" ng-model="currentCommodity" ng-options="commodityitem.commodityName for commodityitem in commodityList">   
    </select>
```