# I can't select a default value from a select option

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I have a problem in selecting the default value of the select option when I try to load the page,this is my code:

```
<select ng-model="sortKey" class="ng-valid ng-pristine">
<option value="LastName" selected="selected">Nom</option>
<option value="FirstName">Prenom</option>
<option value="Class">Classe</option>
</select>
```

I have used the selected="selected" attribute but always I have this problem

[image]

Thanks for help

this is a demo:

```html
<select ng-model="sortKey" style="border-radius: 20px;width: 135px;height: 32px;margin-left:     0px;margin-right: 22px;" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-pristine">
  <option selected value="LastName" >Nom</option>
  <option value="FirstName">Prenom</option>
  <option value="Class">Classe</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works fine. Can you create a demo of the issue?

Comment: thanks  Manoj Kumar for your reply the demo is shown in the picture That I have joined :(

Comment: it shows the result of my code

Comment: If you can create a demo of the full code: http://plnkr.co/ that would be nice.

Comment: Have you tried just using the selected keyword instead of selected = "selected"?

Comment: Should you be using the ngOptions directive? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions Also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815036/setting-default-value-in-select-drop-down-using-angularjs

Comment: Can you show us your live page?