# Angular - how to set a default option in a dropdown list

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, html-select

I'm trying to implement a dropdown list with ngfor, but I have two issue.

1. I don't get a default value selected on the first element. The array is having 4 element. With the first ngFor at the mat-select I want to select 4 items and the first item preferably being selected per default.
2. There is being shown an unwanted empty arrow (line) at the end.

could someone please suggest a better solution. This is my implementations, which I have done after browsing so many post on SO on this topic.

```
  <mat-select *ngFor="let level of myArray; let i=index " placeholder="{{myArray[i+1].name}}">
           <mat-option *ngFor="let child of level.children | keyvalue" value="{{child.value.name}}" >
              {{child.value.name}}
           </mat-option>
            {{level.name}}
  </mat-select>
```

Comment: What default value should be? and on which place first or second? or on which Item? 
We need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]I hope you have the html and the array structure like this. If not please help me out I shall tweak the array structure as per your data.

```
// CSS
 .drop-down-selection{
     min-height: 30px;
     border: 1px solid #000;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
<mat-select *ngFor="let level of myArray; let i=index" placeholder="{{level.name}}" class="drop-down-selection" [(value)]="level.children[0]['name']">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let child of level.children | keyvalue" value="{{child.value.name}}">
      {{child.value.name}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>


    this.myArray = [
                    {
                           name: 'A',
                           children: [
                                   {
                                           name: 'One',
                                           desc: 'No description'
                                   },
                                   {
                                           name: 'Two',
                                           desc: 'No description'
                                   }
                           ] 
                    },
                    {
                           name: 'B',
                           children: [
                                   {
                                           name: 'three',
                                           desc: 'No description'
                                   },
                                   {
                                           name: 'four',
                                           desc: 'No description'
                                   }
                           ] 
                    },
                    {
                           name: 'C',
                           children: [
                                   {
                                           name: 'five',
                                           desc: 'No description'
                                   },
                                   {
                                           name: 'six',
                                           desc: 'No description'
                                   }
                           ] 
                    },
                    {
                           name: 'D',
                           children: [
                                   {
                                           name: 'seven',
                                           desc: 'No description'
                                   },
                                   {
                                           name: 'Two',
                                           desc: 'No description'
                                   }
                           ] 
                    },
                    {
                           name: 'E',
                           children: [
                                   {
                                           name: 'eight',
                                           desc: 'No description'
                                   },
                                   {
                                           name: 'nine',
                                           desc: 'No description'
                                   }
                           ] 
                    }
            ];
```

Let me know if this does not work. I shall tweak something otherwise.

Comment: Thanks everyone. You guys are great.

Comment: Abhijeet Chakravorty: I tried your suggestion on the html, but not is appearing now.

Comment: @user10489212 Anytime . Please do not forget to mark the answer correct if it works for you. Thank you .

Comment: @user10489212 I shall attach the screenshot it works for me. At which point are you facing the problem?

Comment: Yes, please. I would like to see it. I get nothing being displayed. I haven't debugged.

Comment: @user10489212 Please check. I have attached the screenshot in the answer area.

Comment: I will try a few things and see what goes wrong that it doesn't work for me. Appreciate your time. :)

Comment: @user10489212 No problem. Happy to help. I am here please feel free to ping if you still face problems.

Comment: @user10489212 Sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind value with name: **[value]="{{child.value.name}}** instead of **value="{{child.value.name}}"**

That is in this line of code:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let child of level.children | keyvalue" value="{{child.value.name}}" >
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815036/setting-default-value-in-select-drop-down-using-angularjs

Comment: @adelpreore Nope it is not. ng-model is not needed in Angular material for default selection.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the `[(value)]='myDefaultValue` on your `<mat-select>` and in your component.ts add the variable `myDefaultValue = level.children[0].value.name`

Comment: @Nikola and Bogdan I will also try to check with your suggestions.