# angular select with ng-options group by and display an array of values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a simple json

```
    {
      "optgroup1" : ["option11", "option12", "option13"],
      "optgroup2" : ["option21", "option22", "option23"]
    }
```

I want to display this as select using angular ng-options as below:

```
<select>
<optgroup label="optgroup1" value="optgroup1">
<option>option11</option>
<option>option12</option>
<option>option13</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="optgroup2" value="optgroup2">
<option>option21</option>
<option>option22</option>
<option>option23</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Is it possible to use ngOptions (`label group by group for (key, value) in object`
) here?

Comment: You need to change your JSON data :

try this link-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615624/angularjs-ng-options-with-group

Comment: Thanks Mahaveer for the comment. But i dont want to add the group name in all rows. It looks like we have to build optgroup and option through ng-repeat instead of using ngOptions.

Answer (score 0):

in that case you have to know your optgroup what you are going to receive from your json data and check condition for it in your ng-repeat.