# Angular: ng-select option width to a certain group

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I'm trying to set the options width from a group where the ng-select belongs.

Currently it looks like this:

[image: Current ui]

I want to show the options like this:

[image]

My current code is like this:

[image]

I am hoping that I can add something in ng-select to set option width same with form-search. I can't find resources to do this. Any other way would also be helpful. Thanks

Comment: i hope this link help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615624/angularjs-ng-options-with-group?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: use ng-option for this use.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615624/angularjs-ng-options-with-group?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: i don't think the link is helpful. I want the width of the option in a certain group not in the select itself

Comment: can you add some like [style]="{width:100%;padding:0}" in your tag?