# using AngularJS and select tag Data-live-search not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-filter

I'm new to AngularJS. I followed this post [angularjs-ng-options-with-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615624/angularjs-ng-options-with-group) and added data-live-search.

This is my json

```
{"Type":"Orange","NSX":"Group1"},
{"Type":"Apple","NSX":"Group1"},
{"Type":"Grape","NSX":"Group1"},
{"Type":"Flower","NSX":"Group2"}
```

My html:

```
<select data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith" 
 ng-model="val"  class="selectpicker"
 ng-options="x.Type group by x.NSX for x in Farm">              
</select>
```

Image
My select menu:

[image]

The problem is when I choose Orange then the output is Apple.  I choose Apple the output is Grape.  I choose Grape, the output is Flower.

I remove `class="selectpicker"`, it works fine, but there is no searching in select menu.

Is there any solution for this or alternative?

Comment: Can you show all your code?  Preferably on [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: here [MyJSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhmc06tw/) you should put tag script into html

Comment: Oh, `data-live-search` is a bootstrap library?  Yeah, that's probably incompatible with angular's grouping.  You should instead create the `data-live-search` functionality without bootstrap using `filter`.

Comment: can you help me to write an example? i'm new to Angularjs

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial:  https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that `data-live-search` from Bootstrap is incompatible with many Angular features.  Instead, you should recreate the filtering it does with an Angular `filter`.  Here is an example of a `startsWith` filter written in Angular, made for your data:

```
app.filter('startsWith', function () {
    return function (items, input) {
        if(input === undefined || input.length === 0){
          return items;
        }

        var filtered = [];
        var inputMatch = new RegExp(input, 'i');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            if (inputMatch.test(item.Type.substring(0, input.length))) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

[**Working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/sh5nmp68/) with your data