# ngOptions From Simple Key-Value Object

Tags: angularjs

There are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12139152/822480) answers that deal with using ng-option with an object formatted like so:

```
 $scope.opts = [
  {value: 111, text: '1st' },
  {value: 222, text: '2nd' }
];
```

My question is, can it be done with an object formatted like this?

```
$scope.opts = [
  {'111': '1st'},
  {'222': '2nd'}
];
```

[Trying it out](http://plnkr.co/edit/6qaO8rzg85oQ7ELhXpAh?p=preview) doesn't work for me.

Any help?

To clarify:

I'd like the options to be like this `<option value="111">1st</option`, etc, where the browser shows `1st`, and the model returns `111`. Can this be done with an array of simplified objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the answer you point out does not say the same thing as you case. You have an *array* of objects having a single property with different names; the name of the single property is the key, the value is tha value.

The "object" syntax for the select is about an *object*, i.e. in your case it should be:

```
$scope.opts = {
    '111': '1st',
    '222': '2nd'
};
```

What you lose with this? No guaranteed iteration order.

Comment: Thanks @Nikos. You are correct. That answer was referring to an object not an array of objects. Never-the-less, my question still stands: Can it be done with an array of simplified objects (as shown), thus guaranteeing iteration order?

Comment: If not obvious, the answer is no :(