# Select particular item in SELECT drop-down using angularjs when initialized from object array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code of SELECT element like this

```
 select(ng-model="chosenProject" id="chosenProject"  ng-options="c.name for c in selectItems")
```

where `selectItems` are *arrays of objects*, and each object got *name* and *value* fields. Later in `chosenProject.value` I read an object (with value and name fields) of chosen item.

Now I also need to pre-select some element based on its value. If I do `$scope.chosenProject.value=*somevaluenumber*`,  `$scope.chosenProject.value.value =*somevaluenumber*` it does not seem to work.

I can not change the declaration; chosenProject gets the whole object of selected item and that's what I use later in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
angular.forEach($scope.selectItems, function(value){
    if(value.value == someValue){
          $scope.chosenProject = value;
          $scope.$apply();
    }
})
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/FSO2zi96AUbVpWG3v092?p=info

Comment: Somehow still do not work at my end, thought I am going to approve the answer as it works in plnkr :) Any ideas why it is still not fuinctioning?

Comment: Need more information to see why its not working in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set **each option with an value**, you should try use this: 
[How do I set the value property in AngularJS' ng-options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options/22997081#22997081)