# AngularJS ng-repeat key on objects first property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I like to build an select element for ordering data. I like to automatically create options for any property of an object.

**Code**

```
<select class="order" ng-model="model.order">
    <option value="{{key}}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in dataItems[0]">{{key}}</option>
</select>
```

**Data**

```
dataItem: {
 { firstname: "beate", lastname: "lind" }
 { firstname: "john", lastname: "rich" }
}
```

In this case it will take the first object and generate my select options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not correct to use `ng-repeat` on a `select` tag.
Please refer to the `ng-options` attribute which should behave more consistently and give you the desired result:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 0):

@Cranio is correct, `ngOptions` is the correct method when using `select`. Using your code this is what it'd look like.

```
$scope.dataItem = [
 { firstname: "beate", lastname: "lind" }
 { firstname: "john", lastname: "rich" }
]

<select ng-model="model.order" ng-options="(name.firstname + ' ' + name.lastname) for name in dataItem">
    <option value="">[-- select --]</option>
</select>
```

[Live DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/qigEezfNWxPSWbJ5T2PS?p=preview)

This SO post has a lot of helpful answers if you get stuck (there are several other things you can do with `ngOptions`)
[How do I set the value property in AngularJS' ng-options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options)