# Bind one attribute of an array of ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have the following array:

```
[{code: "AF", name: "Afghanistan"}, {code: "ZA", name: "South Africa"}, {code: "AL", name: "Albania"}]
```

I have a select and would like to bind my ng-model only on the code attribute of the selected object and not the whole object. But on the other hand, I would like my select to display only the name (and not the code). In addition, I would like that if I set my ng-model to a code, it will pre-select the name in the selection.

I tried the following (Jade)

```
select(ng-model='myCountry', ng-options='country.name for country in countries track by country.name')
```

Here my ng-model gets the whole object (myCountry = {code: "AF", name: "Afghanistan"}) and not just the code (myCountry = "AF")

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set value property in angularjs ng-options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
  <div>
    <select ng-model="country" ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in countries"></select>
    Selected country (ng-model): {{country}}
  </div>
```

`country.code` - will be used as the `ng-model` attribute.

`country.name` - will be used to display the item in select.

[See the demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gRkmOWXlbaxIikRIGPfj?p=preview).

And if you want to set the select option to a pre-selected value just use the `country` model to supply the value.

Comment: Thanks...but I forgot to say that the selection needs to be sorted by array index. Can you add that easily?

Comment: Those second and third sentences are brilliant champ.