# Set value in Angularjs select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind values to dropdown list, my data is an Object array but can't find a way to bind the id of the selection to the dropdown value.

Here is my code and fiddle

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.optionSource = [{
        "name" : "First Cost",
        "id" : "1"

        }, {
        "name" : "Second",
        "id" : "3"

        }, {
        "name" : "Third",
        "id" : "2"

        }, {
        "name" : "Sone",
        "id" : "5"

        }, {
        "name" : "List  CC",
        "id" : "4"
    }];
    $scope.value = [2,4];
}
```

html

```
<select multiple="multiple" ng-model="value"
    ng-options="option.name for option in optionSource">
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7RUzu/1/

I want the id to be the value.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `as` to specify the value.

```
<select multiple="multiple" ng-model="value"
    ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in optionSource">
</select>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7RUzu/2/)

Comment: thanks man, but can we make the value 1,3,2,5,4 instead of 0,1,2,3,3 screencast.com/t/yRlycnZN

Comment: @MZH It works that way by design. Don't fight the system :) Read the comments on the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options) for an explanation