# Cannot populate values in select box using ng-options

Tags: html, angularjs, list-comprehension, angularjs-ng-options

I have a select box as

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.project.customerAccess" 
                         ng-options="c.customerAccessValue  for c in customerAccessValues">
                         </select>
```

where my customerAccessValues as printedcon console is

[image]

What is it I am missing in comprehension expression.?

Comment: what do you have in `customerAccessValues`

Comment: You are selecting customerAccessValues from customerAccessValues. Should't it be selecting customerAccessValues from customerAccess ?

Comment: @Sravan It is the json array as printed on console. screenshot is attached.

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani I want to select customerAccessValue from customerAccessValues

Comment: try changing the ng-model and check,
`<select ng-model="test" ng-options="c.customerAccessValue  for c in customerAccessValues">
                         </select>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734151/why-is-my-ng-options-not-populating-my-select-input maybe this will help you

Comment: what is the status?

Comment: @Piya Yeah got ip populated i missed $scope while defining customerAccessValues in my controller. Thabkx bu t there is one more issue my first value in select box is empty. what to do about that

Comment: For the empty value : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select

Comment: @Piya Yeah, it was available in the llink you shared previously.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the empty select, just initialize a value in controller.

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.project.customerAccess" 
ng-options="c.customerAccessValue  for c in customerAccessValues">
</select>
```

Controller,

```
$scope.ctrl.project.customerAccess = $scope.customerAccessValues[0]
```