# Angularjs option value change to serial number

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When I am binding my dropdown by using ng-option, the code value change from string to 0, 1, 2.... here is my code

```
<select ng-model="class.code"
   data-ng-form="field"
   data-ng-required="false"
   ng-options="item.code as item.name for item in classes"
   class="form-control" />
```

Here is the json which I used to bind the drop down

```
class.code : 'EQ';
classes: [ { "code": "BU ", "name": "BU " },  
  { "code": "EQ ", "name": "EQ " }, 
  { "code": "IO ", "name": "IO " }, 
  { "code": "LA ", "name": "LA " }, 
  { "code": "VH ", "name": "VH " } ]
```

Copied from browser (check value)

```
<select ng-model="class.code" 
   data-ng-form="field" 
   data-ng-required="false" 
   ng-options="item.code as item.name for item in classes" 
   class="form-control">
   <option selected="selected" value="?"></option>
   <option value="0">BU</option>
   <option value="1">EQ</option>
   <option value="2">IO</option>
   <option value="3">LA</option>
   <option value="4">VH</option>
</select>
```

Why the value is not being used which I passed in my array rather than 0, 1 2 3 ...

Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/9615/

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a fiddle? code looks right

Answer (score 0):

There are spaces at the end of your codes, but not `class.code`.  Also, `class` should be an object - not a function:

```
$scope.class = {
  code: 'EQ '
};
```

I added a trailing space to `class.code`, to match `classes`.  http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/9616/

...

Also, you are missing the closing `</select>` tag.

Comment: If there would be any space then it will contvert to 0 1 2 3 ...., my problem is this

Comment: angular doesn't really care about the value attributes on each option.  if you check out my updated fiddle, you can see that the correct value is getting set.  http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/9653/

Comment: i haven't tried yet, but it looks like a tracking expression might be able to set the option value.. if it really matters.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options