# Angular Js: Can you set the default value for a select in conjunction with using 'track by' in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The best method to set the values for your options in your select list, seems to be to use 'track-by' (using a.id as a.name seems to be out-dated) in your ng-options directive. However, when I use 'track by', I am no longer able to set the default value using ng-model.

Take for example, this plunkr: 
    http://plnkr.co/edit/OZCal9ZkCQeqnQJY0WP9?p=preview

```
  <select ng-model="class.team.leader" ng-options="student.name for student in curTeam.students track by student._id">
```

Currently, the plunkr correctly sets the default value. However, if you change it to use 'track by', like in the code above, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`track by` doesn't work like that. It's used to compare a property on both objects rather than checking for object equality. ie `obj1.trackBy === obj2.trackBy` rather than `obj1 === obj2`.

For example, change your default model to:

```
$scope.class = {
    team: {
       leader: { _id: 2, name: 'Dave', status: 0 }
    }  
};
```

Without `track by` this wouldn't work as it's a different object to what's in the students array. But with `track by` angular will compare the `_id` properties to decide equality.

Comment: I am using 'track by' as used in this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options
It sets the value on the option fields. I feel that you are using trackBy for a different use, but I will read it again as I am probably getting confused.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. If your model is just the id property then `a.id as a.name` is not outdated and should be used

Comment: As with the top comment for the selected answer: "Your example doesn't fill value attribute of option. It defines what would be stored in the model of <select> element. See difference between obj.value as obj.text and obj.text". As I want the value attribute to be set, I want to use track by.

Comment: It's not possible to change the value attribute, they are always 0, 1, 2, etc. Why do you need to set the value?

Comment: It is possible to change the value attribute. Just replace the plnkr in the question with the line of code that I have provided. Inspect the html and you will see that the value attribute is equal to the id.

Comment: I stand corrected. What I posted [seems to work](http://plnkr.co/edit/jduccryiJFygsM9VuOG7?p=preview). Though if you want the `id as` bit as well that doesn't seem to play nicely. Possible workaround [here](http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/)

Comment: Thanks. This works nicely without having to use the workaround. 
I had seen that workaround, but didn't want to use it because it seems like a hack. I am not sure why they feel the need for this. I do not get the issues that they claim to have. I was having seemingly similar issues, because of an unrelated issue with asynchronous ajax calls coming back in an unexpected order. Thanks for your help.