# How to display the id of a object from a select box

Tags: angularjs

I have a select box with a list of Employees. when i select one it is sending the string value to the controller. I need to pass the Id of the selected name, not the name value itself. 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mpKUYx0BKw1AgBXk4CPQ?p=preview)

```
 <label>CustomerPM:</label>
 <select style="width: 150px" ng-options="customer.CustomerEmployeeFirstName + ' ' + customer.CustomerEmployeeLastName as customer.CustomerEmployeeFirstName + ' ' + customer.CustomerEmployeeLastName for customer in customerEmployeeArray | filter:{CustomerEmployeeRole : 'PM', CustomerId : currentItem.CustomerId}" ng-model="currentItem.CustomerEmployeePMId"> 
   <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
      &nbsp;
   </select><br />
     {{currentItem.CustomerEmployeePMId}}<br />
      <label>CustomerSuper:</label>
   <select style="width: 150px" ng-options="customer.CustomerEmployeeFirstName + ' ' + customer.CustomerEmployeeLastName as customer.CustomerEmployeeFirstName + ' ' + customer.CustomerEmployeeLastName for customer in customerEmployeeArray | filter:{CustomerEmployeeRole : 'Super', CustomerId : currentItem.CustomerId} " ng-model="currentItem.CustomerEmployeeSuperId">
     <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
       &nbsp;
    </select><br />
    {{currentItem.CustomerEmployeeSuperId}}<br/>
```

Comment: I do not see that `<option>` has any id to work with.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options) should be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first part of your `ng-options` attribute, `customer.CustomerEmployeeFirstName + ' ' + customer.CustomerEmployeeLastName as` -- and replace it with `customer.CustomerEmployeeId as`

From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select):

> `select`: The result of this expression will be bound to the model of the parent  element. If not specified, select expression will default to value.