# Ng-options doesn't apply value when selecting an element

Tags: angularjs

I have some values saved in `ng-options` , when you selec the element it doesn't give the proper value to the box, I want to change height and width of that element using `<option>` element.

My HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select
                ng-options="p.first + ' x ' + p.last for p in people"
                ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>

        {{ selectedPerson.first }} x {{ selectedPerson.last }}
    </fieldset>

    <div class="box" ng-style="{'width' : selectedPerson.first}">

    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.people = [
        { id: 1, first: 100, last: 200 },
        { id: 2, first: 200, last: 300 },
        { id: 3, first: 300, last: 400 },
        { id: 4, first: 400, last: 500 }
    ];
});
```

A Fiddle used for the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/a6p1fL7m/

Comment: Please go through the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options , it helps to solve your problem

Comment: Make sure your ng-style="{'width' : selectedPerson.first}" should come under controller element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a controller on your fieldset, it has a separate scope that is unavailable to it's siblings.  For example if you put the div inside your fieldset, and add 'px' to the width it works ([***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/9ch7bksq/)):

```
<fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <select
            ng-options="p.first + ' x ' + p.last for p in people"
            ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>

    {{ selectedPerson.first }} x {{ selectedPerson.last }}
    <div class="box" ng-style="{'width' : selectedPerson.first + 'px'}">
      selectedPerson: {{selectedPerson|json}}
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I always find it handy for debugging to throw the value in there with the `| json` filter to make sure the value is correct where I think it should be.  You can also use the [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) chrome extension to help debug your scopes.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works and fits my neeeds! Sometimes is hard to figure out what is the proper scope. Thanks again!