# How to assign id to select option value using anjular.js

Tags: mysql, angularjs, perl

I have a mysql table. Table schema is -

```
table_categories - category_id, category_name
```

This is my perl cose to get the data from the taable and convert it into json format.

```
my $sql_query = "SELECT * from table_categories order by category_name";
my $statement = $db_handle->prepare ($sql_query) or die "Couldn't prepare query '$sql_query': $DBI::errstr\n";  
$statement->execute() or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";  

my @loop_data = ();
my $count = 0;

while (my @data = $statement->fetchrow_array())
{
    push(@loop_data, \@data);
    $count++;
}

my $json;

$json->{"entries"} = \@loop_data;
$json->{"count"} = $count;

print to_json($json);
$db_handle->disconnect;
```

I am trying to fill "select" in HTML using angular.js

```
<select ID="select-add-new-product-catty-name" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="category[0] as category[1] for category in categories.entries"></select>
```

The problem is data is getting filled, but the category_id assigned to "option" value is in sequence , i.e. 1,2,3,4. I want actual category_id to be assigned to option value.

What is missing here. Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: You should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your select tag you need the following:

```
<option ng-repeat="item in itemsReturnedFromYourAjaxCall" value="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
```

Comment: Can i know, what is the difference between this and the one i'm using?

Comment: ng-repeat will create option list in the DOM.
Doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat
Plunker to play: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview