# How to set the initial ng-model value for a <select> to pass to function without needing to change the select?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework, ng-options

Sorry if this is already answered but I have looked through a lot of questions and just can't get this right.

Using angulaJS  with the following declaration to create my select from a JSON object. The select creates perfectly and the item is correctly set using the ng-selected option.

```
<select ng-model="assignment.status">
            <option ng-selected="instanceData.status.current" ng-repeat="status in instanceData.status.list" value="{{status.id}}">{{status.title}}</option>
</select>
```

The issue I have is that when I execute an update  on ng-click function which passes the value of assignment (ng-model) the value is not being passed to the function unless the select has been changed.

```
<a class="button button-positive" ng-click="save_status_assignment(assignment)">Update</a>
```

Is there anyone out there that can help me please?

Many Thanks
B

Comment: Refer this: http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/ or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12140310/1364558

Comment: Thank you for your links, they were a great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to assign a value to $scope.assignment.status by default.

Right now, that variable is empty, so it won't give you anything.
So something like this in your controller would work

```
$scope.assignment = {};
// Assuming you want the default to be the first value
$scope.assignment.status = $scope.instanceData.status.list[0].id;
```

Then you are good to go.

**Edit**

Also, you should use ng-options instead of ng-repeat for your options.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Thanks for this, I can see how simple it is, duh moment ;) Thanks again!! I have also converted to using ng-options. Working great!