# Binding select with ng-options using an array of labels and values

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I for the life of me cannot figure out how to set both the labal and the value of a select using an array

I have an array of countries

```
$scope.countries =  [
    {abbr:"US", name:"United States"},
    {abbr:"CA", name:"Canada"},......
]
```

I want the select to generate as such

```
<select>
  <option value="US">United States</option>
  <option value="CA">Canada</option>
</select>
```

However the closest I have been able to achieve is

```
<select>
  <option value="1">United States</option>
  <option value="2">Canada</option>
</select>
```

I've achieved that using

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="country.Name for country in countries" ng-model="selectedCountry">
```

How do I assign the label AND the value using ng-options?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions. The angular docs tell you how to do this.

Comment: This already has been answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing I think it's just

```
ng-options="country.abbr as country.name for country in countries"
```

Comment: This is what I thought, but it produces a numbered value instead of my abbreviation value

Comment: Wow that's a little harsh - http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/uaxv70kc/  - it does work.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were correct. Apparently I was correct all along too. I was looking at the generated HTML and not at what was actually being stored in the model. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For exact structure, you need to do `ng-repeat` through your `<option><option>` `ng-options` will never set the value which which you want, It will always set 0,1,2,3 etc.

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry">
    <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.abbr}}" ng-bind="country.name"></option>
</select>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uaxv70kc/2/)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: @user1691808 if it does helpful then atleast do voteup..Thanks.