# ng-options returns object instead of actual options value

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects:

```
$scope.allCategories = [{'name': 'cat1', 'description: ... },
                        {'name': 'cat2', 'description: ... }, 
                        {...}];
```

I was previously using:

```
<select ng-model="mycategory" ng-change="test()">
    <option ng-repeat="category in allCategories">{{ category.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Which worked fine, but it's not the "Angular way". So I have changed it to:

```
<select ng-model="mycategory" ng-change="test()" ng-options="category.name for category in allCategories track by category.name"></select>
```

Which builds this correct html:

```
<select ...>
<option value="cat1" label="cat1">cat1</option>
<option value="cat2" label="cat2">cat2</option>
...
</select>
```

However in my `test()`:

```
// called whenever select changes
$scope.test = function() {
    console.log($scope.mycategory);   
}
```

`$scope.mycategory` prints out the object `{'name': 'cat1', 'description: ... }` instead of the string value. The previous version with `ng-repeat` would give me the string value, so this threw me off.

Is there a way to get the string value automatically without doing `$scope.mycategory = $scope.mycategory['name'];` inside my `test()`?

Comment: Use `category.name as category.name for category in allCategories track by category.name` instead. See [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Comment: I think this is a duplicate to this issue.  Hope this helps.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-the-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options/30291578#30291578

Answer (score 1):

Here is code :

```
<select ng-model="correctlySelected"
    ng-options="category.name as category.name for category in allCategories">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get exact selected value change your test method as follows:

```
$scope.test = function() {
console.log($scope.mycategory);}
```

change your html part as

```
<select ng-model="mycategory" ng-change="test()" ng-options="category.name for category in allCategories"></select>
```