# How can i set auto selected value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am getting a value in json andand  want to put that value in selectbox html auto sleceted that in angularjs how can i do this?

Here is my html code

```
<select class="form-control" name="comregtype"  ng-init="users.comregtype" id="comregtype" ng-options="c.name for c in colors" >
                       <option  ng-selected="users.comregtype"  ></option>
                      <option>Company Registration Type</option>
                           <option>Proprietor</option>
                           <option>Partnership Firm</option>
                           <option>LLP</option>
                           <option>Pvt. Ltd. Co.</option>
                           <option>Ltd. Co.</option>
                        </select>
```

JS:  `$scope.users = {comregtype:response.comregtype}`

i am gettting value in `response.comregtype = "LLP"`

How can i set this as seleceted value in selecetbox.

if anyone can help .

Thanks

Comment: @shakthi did you check

Comment: dublicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-to-set-the-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

```
  <select ng-model="value" ng-init="value='LLP'"   ng-options="mode.value as mode.value for mode in types.RegistrationType">
  </select>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/mrDDsXJ01jH3FxlGoKF2?p=preview)