# How can i change the selected ng-options option's name to something custom?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-select

The following code will do the option name to the id.

```
<select ng-model="vm.ships" ng-change="vm.updateShip()"  data-ng-options="ship as ship._id for ship in vm.readyships">
```

Q: How can i make the name something to be "ship `ship.id` is ready ( `ship.to`) " ?

is that even possible to do with ng-options?

wanted result:

```
<option value="0" selected="selected" label="57e261">ship 57e261 is ready (sweden) </option>
```

UPDATE:

variable `ship.to` is avaliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing what you want in the label portion of the `data-ng-options`. In order to get the full label you can concatenate on the additional text:

```
<select ng-model="vm.ships" ng-change="vm.updateShip()"  data-ng-options="ship as ('ship' + ship._id + ' is ready (' + ship.to + ')') for ship in vm.readyships">
```

In addition to the documentation, this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12140310/5638411) sums up the different options you have with `ng-options`.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible, if the `to` is part of your `array`.

```
ng-options="obj as obj.to for obj in results"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ship.to` exists:

```
<select ng-model="vm.ships" ng-change="vm.updateShip()" data-ng-options="ship as ship._id + ' is ready (' + ship.to + ')' for ship in vm.readyships">
```