# Ng-show in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to hide this tag when it doesn't have a subcategory, I used `item.length != 0` but it doesn't work.

```
    <multi-select-tree class="multiselectStyle groupStyle" 
           data-input-model="categoryTree" 
           multi-select="true" data-output-model="selectAllCategory"
           ng-show="item.length!=0" //is wrong! 
           data-default-label="select article group"
           data-callback ="selectOnlyCategory(item, selectedItems)">
    </multi-select-tree>

    $scope.selectOnlyCategory = function(item, selectedItems) {
        if (selectedItems !== undefined && selectedItems.length >= 20) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Item is as entrance value in "selectOnlyCategory(item, selectedItems)"

Comment: @mahdikhodadadian please include some code to explain the structure of your `item`.

Comment: Is this an object ? Please update your question with the item. Where is the subcategory ?

Comment: can you post you categoryTree with some dummy json

Comment: why are you passing 'item' as a parameter if you don't use it?

Comment: Subcategory generate in it , like this : <tree-item></tree-item>

Comment: If it is false say to me what I should pass except item ?

Comment: @mahdikhodadadian I think that you should ask a friend/colleague to help you to ask a well-formed question. You are absolutely not clear and you don't understand our remarks

Comment: @Weedoze Ok Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the value property in AngularJS' ng-options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-do-i-set-the-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options)

Answer (score 1):

try to use data-ng-if, this will keep your html light, the item is not even generated if the condition is not met try to do this. 
Assumption : your controller is passing some value to $scope.item

```
data-ng-if="item.length > 0"
```

Comment: Without trying it out myself, I think this is the right answer

Comment: maybe try ng-if="item && item.length > 0". maybe item is undefined or null and has no 'length'? is item an array?

Comment: Why are you trying ? You do not even know what is `item`

Comment: whats the value of your $scope.item, can you try to print it in console
or are you able to print it any where in your html using {{item}}

Comment: Item is the entry value that I use it to pass value with it!

Comment: do you want to use selectedItems instead of items ?

Comment: You mean this : ng-if="selectedItems.length > 0" ?

Comment: may be, but that depends upon your use case. Also you can use  ng-init="item=<whatever here>"