# angular js I have a dynamic json and i want it to used in ng-option

Tags: angularjs

This is json like this -`[{"1":"B"},{"2":"A"},{"100":"E"},{"104":"P"},{"105":"A"},{"1551":"D"}]`

and want it to create an select tag which should be look like this

```
<select name="">
   <option value="1">B</option>
   <option value="2">A</option>
   <option value="100">E</option>
   ...
</select>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-do-i-set-the-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options#22997081

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [{"1":"B"},{"5":"A"}];
  
  $scope.getData = function(){
     var d = {};
     angular.forEach($scope.data,function(value,key){
       for(var v in value){
        d[v] = value[v];
       }
    });
    return d;
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <select ng-model="sel" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in getData()"></select>
</div>
```