# Using ng-options to get attribute in array

Tags: angularjs

js-fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4z5ufbuu/

I'm trying to select a value from an array I have via a select option. here are my options:

```
$scope.categories = [
        { type: "Web Application", cssClass: "webApplication" },
        {  type: "Unity", cssClass: "unity" },
    ];

$scope.filterValue = "";
```

I have it so the select displays the "type" but I want the "filterValue" to represent the cssClass.

I have seen this page:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12384319/9132034

but dont really understand this answer:

```
obj = { '1': '1st', '2': '2nd' };

<select ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in obj"></select>
```

guidance would be absolutely perfect or even the solution but that is up to you :)

Comment: Read the official angularjs documentation. That should clear your doubts: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `ng-options` to be:

`ng-options="item.cssClass as item.type for item in categories track by item.cssClass"`

This is saying to use `item.cssClass` as the value while displaying `type` as the label

it is documented in the angularjs official documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/#ngOptions-info

Edit: updated JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4z5ufbuu/4/