# How to build dynamic search box using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, servicenow

I am currently working in Servicenow Service portal where it support Angular

I am able to create a Search box using bootstrap as shown below:

```html
 <select class="mdb-select md-form" searchable="Search here..">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your country</option>
  <option value="1">USA</option>
  <option value="2">Germany</option>
  <option value="3">France</option>
  <option value="3">Poland</option>
  <option value="3">Japan</option>
</select>
```

This gives the correct result. But from the server I am pulling country names which I want set up dynamically upon every update the result may change. I am able to receive a country names as shown below in an array like: Thailand, China, India, Singapore.

How can I set above all the country names in the select box?

Comment: what do you mean by "upon every update the result may change"?

Comment: @Nick Parsons, based on the user we are pulling out the countries result. For every user result of listed countries may change so i want to set the option using a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server script, set the global `data` object property which you can then reference in your HTML.

**Server Script**:

```
// perform a query to get your countries array: 
var countries = ["Thailand", "China", "India", "Singapore"];

data.countries = countries.map(function(text, i) {
  return {value: i+1, text: text};
});
```

Then, in your HTML, to iterate the data and create `<option>` tags dynamically, you can use `ng-options` in your `<select>`

**HTML Template**:

```
<select class="mdb-select md-form" 
  ng-options="obj.text for obj in data.countries track by obj.value"
  ng-model="c.data.selectedCountry" searchable="Search here..">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your country</option>
</select>
```

Above, the value selected is reflected to the `c.data.selectedCountry` variable defined on in your client script.

**Client Script**:

```
function() {
  /* widget controller */
  var c = this;
  c.data.selectedCountry = ""; // changes based on value selected in dropdown

  // other code...
}
```

Comment: Sir, I just copy pasted but i am getting an empty result, i see only Choose your country field when i click i unable to open that :(

Comment: @AbdulAzeez sorry, see update (I had to add `data` to `countries` in the `ng-options`)

Comment: No sir, still it is empty :(
if by any chance can you look at my instance ?
https://dev51617.service-now.com/sp_config?id=widget_editor&sys_id=915c1a882f37c810209857892799b695&spa=1
admin / 12345

Comment: @AbdulAzeez I looked at your instance. You're doing `countries.map()` when `countries` is a string. Do `nameArray.map()` instead. I've updated the instance for you so it should be working. I also added change event function which prints the value of the selected value when the dropdown is changed

Comment: Thank you Sir.. One last question can you please explain me this line of code:  
ng-options="obj.text for obj in data.countries track by obj.value" ? What it does, i dont see i defined obj anywhere in the server side

Comment: @AbdulAzeez it is responsible for creating the <option> tags in the dropdown. The `for obj in data.countries` part defines `obj` the current iterated object in the loop. The `obj.text` part grabs the text for the current object and specifies it to be the text in the option. The `track by obj.value` grabs the value of the current object and specifies it to be the current value. A more detailed answer can be found here: [How do I set the value property in AngularJS' ng-options?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12139152)

Comment: Got it you. Thank you So mcuh

Comment: i got struck up at some place can you please look into it ?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/60801221/12309720

Comment: @AbdulAzeez looks like your figured it out?

Comment: Yes Nick. Thank you :)

Comment: Sir, I again need your help i am sorry to trouble you. Can you please help me on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825934/how-to-pass-values-from-server-to-html-in-servicenow-service-portal

Answer (score 0):

Although I am a react guy but as far as I know it can be done in this way. So lets say you have the countries array.

```
$scope.countries = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'USA'
}, 
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'France',
}];

<select class="selectpicker" 
 ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries track by 
 country.id" 
 ng-model="selected">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of the fix, I understand you need to use a normal select tag, so I have provided a solution without using any custom select plugin, please let me know if this fixes your issue.

HTML Code:

```
<select class="mdb-select md-form" id="test" searchable="Search here.." multiple #selectBox (change)="onChange($event.target)">
  <option value="" disabled>Choose your country</option>
  <option 
    *ngFor="let item of countries" 
    [value]="item.id" 
    [selected]="userCountries.indexOf(item.id) > -1">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Component code:

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  userCountries = [
    1,2,3,4
  ];
  countries = [
    {
      name: 'USA',
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      name: 'Germany',
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      name: 'France',
      id: 3,
    },
    {
      name: 'Poland',
      id: 4,
    },
    {
      name: 'Japan',
      id: 5,
    },
  ];

  onChange(selectCtrl) {
    const values = Object.keys(selectCtrl['selectedOptions']).map(key => selectCtrl['selectedOptions'][key]);
    const output = values.map((item: HTMLOptionElement) => item.value);
    this.userCountries = values.map((item: HTMLOptionElement) => +item.value);
    console.log(this.userCountries);
  }
}
```

Stack blitz example: <kbd>**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnk36d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use library `bootstrap-select`, the demo code as bellow

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```

You can check more sample [here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: He want to use current library `mdbootstrap`, so you shoud better find a solution with it, before suggesting as new library.