# Change selected option label from ng-option, angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to figure out if there is a way such that I display certain options on a dropdown, but on select, the display label is different. Below is a basic scenario I am trying to solve.

```
$scope.availableOptions = [
    {optionNm: "Gabrial: 20/05/2007", selectedNm: "Gabriel"},
    {optionNm: "Jake: 22/10/2007", selectedNm: "Jake"},
    {optionNm: "Abby: 20/06/2007", selectedNm: "Abby"},
]
$scope.selectedOption = ''
```

And my html snippet is:

```
<select
   ng-model="selectedOption"
   ng-options="opt.optionNm for opt in availableOptions track by opt.optionNm">
 </select>
```

Right now by select box will display Gabrial: 20/05/2007 but I want to display Gabriel

UPDATE

To be clear,  I want my options to display e.g. Gabriel: 20/05/2007, but once I select it, I want the display box to just display Gabriel

Comment: Check out this link, it explains this very well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139152/how-do-i-set-the-value-property-in-angularjs-ng-options

Comment: Thanks for like link Steven, unfortunately I want the option values to remain <name> <date> format, but once I select an option, I want it to only display (the select input box) just the name.

Comment: In that case, you should create a custom directive that will basically wrap the `<select>` element.  

Otherwise, you could also leverage the `ng-change` directive and manipulate the data array object properties you use in `ng-options`.  This is not a great approach, but it is possible.  Write unit tests!